# how to scroll top of the page automatically when page is submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Am working with angularjs in MVC architecture with thymeleaf. i want to push my page automatically to top when page is submitted or page is refreshed automatically.

I came to know that using below function it is achievable. But where exactly i have to write it ( have to write in script file or everypages of thymeleaf HTML page ?)and how to use in thymeleaf pages.

If i write in script file then how to and where to use that id in thymeleaf HTML pages?

```
$window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('put here your element').offsetTop);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) I think it will provide what you're looking for.

It can scroll to a named input or the latest value of $location.hash()

As an example, here would be your method to submit the page:

```
submitForm() {
  doStuff(); // Shortening what you would do for submitting;

  this._$anchorScroll('#named-element-id');
}
```

Another example would be using the $location.hash() if you had set it elsewhere in your controller. Then you could call $anchorScroll() directly without an argument.

Comment: Yeah exactly what am looking for. There is no auto scrolling effect when i used this.Can you help me how to use or where to place this function so that it should work on all the pages of my web application.